# c++ output of stars using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to do this exercise.

Write a recursive function to generate a pattern of stars such as the following:

```
*
**
***
****
****
***
**
*
```

It seems simple but is giving me a lot of problems. I can only output this

```
*
**
***
****
```

using the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void outputStars(int);

int main()
{
    outputStars(5);
    return 0;
}

void outputStars(int num)
{
    if (num == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    outputStars(--num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num  ; i++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }

    cout << endl;   
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Have you considered doing something on the path down to the anchor *and* doing something on the path up from the anchor?

Comment: I think you should start with getting `outputStars(1)` to work. And mutations, like decrementing variables, usually don't go well with recursion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursively printing a star pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544270/recursively-printing-a-star-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You are only printing the stars when you return from the call. Also print it before you call.

I've modified it to take 2 arguments. `i` specifies number of times `*` is to be printed in a call

```
void outputStars(int num,int i)
{
    if (i == num)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (int j = 0 ;j < i; j++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;

    outputStars(num,i+1);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Call it as

```
outputStars(5,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rec_fun(int x);
void print_stars(int times, int x);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    rec_fun(5);

    return 0;
}

void rec_fun(int x)
{
    static int times = x;

    if (x <= 0)
        return;

    print_stars(times, x);
    rec_fun(x - 1);
    if (x != 1)
        print_stars(times, x);

}

void print_stars(int times, int x)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < times - x + 1; i++)
        printf("*");
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: here is what is most likely an answer to your homework... You should try to find another way yourself, that _is_ the point of homework